# I want to disable background when i click button popup

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't disable background when I open popup, I want hide or make it shadow but I don't know how to add css, please help with my code, I'm a newbie in develop. Thanks for help!

```
        <div class="searchbox">
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Tìm phòng trọ theo từ khóa" size="25">
                <button class="btn" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </form>
        </div>
       <div class="login">  
             <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('loginbox').style.display ='block'">Đăng nhập ngay</button>
         </div>

        <div id="loginbox">
            <img src="images/avatar1.jpg" class="avatar">
            <h1>Đăng Nhập</h1>
            <form>
                <p>Tên đăng nhập</p>
                <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Điền tên đăng nhập">
                <p>Mật khẩu</p>
                <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Mật khẩu">
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Đăng nhập">
                <a href="Register.html">Chưa có tài khoản ?</a>
                <button onclick="button" onclick="document.getElementById('loginbox').style.display ='none'">Close</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

And CSS for this

```
#loginbox{
  width: 320px;
  height: 420px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #fff;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 70px 30px;
  display:none;
}

body{
  background-image:url(images/background2.png) ;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100vh;        
}
```

Comment: you want to hide something when you click the login button?

Comment: @IrkenInvader yes i want to hide background or opacity can u teach me how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myfunc(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
  

    if (element) {
        var display = element.style.display;

        if (display == "block") {
            element.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            element.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}

function overlayOn(){
  document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';
}

function overlayOff(){
  document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
body{
background-image:url(http://www.jquery-az.com/html/images/banana.jpg) ;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
  height: 100vh;
}

#loginbox{
width: 320px;
height: 420px;
background-color: white;
color: #fff;
top: 45%;
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 70px 30px;
  display:none;
  z-index: 2;
  
}

.overlay
{
   position:fixed;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="searchbox">
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Tìm phòng trọ theo từ khóa" size="25">
                <button class="btn" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </form>
        </div>
       <div class="login">  
             <button type="button" onclick="myfunc('loginbox');overlayOn()">Đăng nhập ngay</button>
         </div>

        <div id="loginbox">
            <img src="images/avatar1.jpg" class="avatar">
            <h1>Đăng Nhập</h1>
            <form>
                <p>Tên đăng nhập</p>
                <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Điền tên đăng nhập">
                <p>Mật khẩu</p>
                <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Mật khẩu">
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Đăng nhập">
                <a href="Register.html">Chưa có tài khoản ?</a>
                <button onclick="button" onclick="myfunc('loginbox')">Close</button>
            </form>
        </div>
  <div id='overlay' onclick="myfunc('loginbox');overlayOff()" class='overlay' style="display:none;"></div>
  </body>
```

If you want to make just toggle, so change it

```
onclick="document.getElementById('loginbox').style.display ='none'"
onclick="document.getElementById('loginbox').style.display ='block'"
```

to

```
onclick="myfunc('loginbox')"
```

and add function to javascript

```
function myfunc(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);

    if (element) {
        var display = element.style.display;

        if (display == "block") {
            element.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            element.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

UPD: add overlay for background

Comment: i want background opacity can u help me ?

Comment: what do you mean with opacity?

Comment: it mean when popup open and background opacity, can u show me how to do it ?

Comment: opacity for background image?

Comment: I've updated snipet. Check it and if you like accept my answer please)

Comment: I am glad that it's helpful. Do not forget accept the answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background color from JavaScript after you click a button you should use this code:

```html
<button onclick='removeBackground()'>Click me!</button>
```

JavaScript:

```js
function removeBackground() {
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
}
```

If you want to hide a button after you click it, you should use:

```html
<button onclick='hideButton()' id='hide'>Hide me!</button>
```

```js
function hideButton() {
document.getElementById('hide').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

If you want it to not take up any space on the web-page do this for JavaScript:

```js
function hideButton() {
document.getElementById('hide').style.visibility = 'collapse';
}
```